# How to avoid GROUP BY or DISTINCT in UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-server

I have a table like this

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
00002471    Sd3a28d471  0   24.00   377.500000  1
00002471    Sd3a28d471  0   353.50  377.500000  1
00002471    Sd3a28d471  1   211.00  211.000000  1

00002471    Sd3a28e471  1   343.00  343.000000  1
00002471    Sd3a28e471  0   56.00   242.370000  1
00002471    Sd3a28e471  0   177.06  242.370000  1
00002471    Sd3a28e471  0   9.31    242.370000  1

00002471    Sd3a28f471  0   10.31   10.31   1
00002471    Sd3a28f471  1   10.31   10.31   1
```

By grouping the columns A, B and C, I need to check which one has the lowest value in E and update the F column to 1 for the lowest value rows and rest of the columns to 0. In case the value is the same I need to update the F column to 1 where C is 1. The output I need is below

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
00002471    Sd3a28d471  0   24.00   377.500000  0
00002471    Sd3a28d471  0   353.50  377.500000  0
00002471    Sd3a28d471  1   211.00  211.000000  1

00002471    Sd3a28e471  1   343.00  343.000000  0
00002471    Sd3a28e471  0   56.00   242.370000  1
00002471    Sd3a28e471  0   177.06  242.370000  1
00002471    Sd3a28e471  0   9.31    242.370000  1

00002471    Sd3a28f471  0   10.31   10.31   0
00002471    Sd3a28f471  1   10.31   10.31   1
```

I tried this below query

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.F = CASE WHEN T1.E <= T2.E THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
--select t2.*
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT A,B,C,D,E,F FROM #SalesOrder WHERE E IS NOT NULL) T1 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT A,B,C,D,E,F FROM #SalesOrder WHERE E IS NOT NULL) T2                           
ON  T1.A    = T2.A
AND T1.B    = T2.B
--AND T1.C  = T2.C
WHERE T1.C = 1 AND T2.C = 0
```

But this query is throws an error

> Error Message
>   Msg 4418, Level 16, State 1, Line 265
>   Derived table 'T1' is not updatable because it contains aggregates, or a DISTINCT or GROUP BY clause, or PIVOT or UNPIVOT operator.

@Suresh Gajera
I need to take the distinct values of A,B,C and E, after taking distinct the values it will be like this

```
A   B   C   E
00002471    Sd3a28d471  0   377.500000
00002471    Sd3a28d471  1   211.000000
00002471    Sd3a28e471  0   242.370000
00002471    Sd3a28e471  1   343.000000
00002471    Sd3a28f471  0   10.31   
00002471    Sd3a28f471  1   10.31
```

After this I need to compare the value of E based on C column, in this the second row is lowest when compare to the first row, so 2 row should be 1 and first should be 0...In the same way third and fourth row should be updated..when comes to 5th and 6th rows the value is same in this case, I need to update the F column to 1 where C is 1

Comment: And why avoid grouing?

Comment: I was getting an error when using group by or distinct in the update statement, error details below..

Msg 4418, Level 16, State 1, Line 265
Derived table 'T1' is not updatable because it contains aggregates, or a DISTINCT or GROUP BY clause, or PIVOT or UNPIVOT operator.

Comment: Please add that error message and the query you tried into your question by editing it

Comment: Can you please help me to understand why 3rd row has value   = 1 and 4th row has value = 0 in F column. did not understand the logic.

Comment: If i have understand your problem statement correctly then you need to group only A and B . there is no need to group by C . This is what i feel after looking your expected output.

Comment: I elaborate my query in the question itself, please have a look at it

Comment: Grouping by A, B, C gives you three groups: rows (1,2), (3), (4), (5,6,7). For rows (1,2) the lowest E is in both, so why do they get F 0 and not F 1? Same for row 4. Do you mean grouping by A, B only maybe?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, It was typo, I corrected the value.

Comment: No, I mean you seem to want to look at groups per A,B, but you say you want grouping by A,B,C. See the first phrase in the answer you have accepted; forpas also thinks that you are mistaken taking about grouping per A, B, C.

Comment: Anyway, it is usually a very bad idea to store aggregation results in rows. You should rather select the values on-the-fly. `select a,b,c,d,e, case when (min(e) over (partition by a,b) = max(e) over (partition by a,b) and c = 1) or (min(e) over (partition by a,b) < max(e) over (partition by a,b) and e = min(e) over (partition by a,b)) then 1 else 0 end as f from #salesorder order by a,b,e`.

Comment: The case that all rows of a group have the same value, but differ in c is not in your example and is not covered in forpas' answer, if I understand your request correctly.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner the query which you gave is exactly giving the output I need, but I need an update statement to update the existing column in table rather than creating a new column, will you be able to help on this...
thanks for the above query

Comment: As metioned that's usually a bad idea. Anyway, if forpas is correct with the syntax, it's `with cte as ( select *, case when (min(e) over (partition by a,b) = max(e) over (partition by a,b) and c = 1) or (min(e) over (partition by a,b) < max(e) over (partition by a,b) and e = min(e) over (partition by a,b)) then 1 else 0 end as fnew from #salesorder ) update cte set f = fnew;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expected results make sense only if you group by A and B (without C).
In this case:

```
update t
set t.f = case when t.e = tt.mine then 1 else 0 end
from tablename t inner join (
  select a, b, min(e) mine
  from tablename   
  group by a, b
) tt 
on tt.a = t.a and tt.b = t.b
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=00929bd46ea11f7e1cd621be9e0e3e73).
Or with a `CTE` and window function `MIN()`:

```
with cte as (
  select *, min(e) over (partition by a, b) mine
  from tablename 
)
update cte
set f = case when e = mine then 1 else 0 end
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9be8c04786cb5cf0a275a4a2d6354dcd).
Results:

```
>    A | B          |  C |   D | E      |  F
> ---: | :--------- | -: | --: | :----- | -:
> 2471 | Sd3a28d471 |  0 |  24 | 377.50 |  0
> 2471 | Sd3a28d471 |  0 | 353 | 377.50 |  0
> 2471 | Sd3a28d471 |  1 | 211 | 211.00 |  1
> 2471 | Sd3a28e471 |  1 | 343 | 343.00 |  0
> 2471 | Sd3a28e471 |  0 |  56 | 242.37 |  1
> 2471 | Sd3a28e471 |  0 | 177 | 242.37 |  1
> 2471 | Sd3a28e471 |  0 |   9 | 242.37 |  1
```

Comment: thanks for your help @forpas  In the above two options which one should I prefer based on performance?

Comment: Window functions usually perform better in a large dataset, so I suggest the 2nd query.

Comment: I just tried your query, when the values are not equal, it is working fine, but when the values are equal it is not working..@forpas

Comment: As you can see in the demo the query is working with your sample data. So where is the problem?

Comment: By grouping the columns A, B and C, I need to check which one has the lowest value in E and update the F column to 1 for the lowest value rows and rest of the columns to 0. 
In case the value is the same I need to update the F column to 1 where C is 1, but with this query, it is updating F column to 1 where C is 1 also where C is 0...@forpas

Comment: If you group by a,b,c then the results would not be like the expected results in your question. Can you explain why you want those 0s in the expected results if you group by a,b,c?

Comment: I updated the question by the adding the new values which have same value in E in case of C has 0 or 1 and updated the output I need as well...Hope it is clear..

Comment: Can you explain the row: `00002471    Sd3a28f471  0   10.31   10.31   0` why 0 in the results? 10.31 is the min e if you group by a.b,c.

Comment: A   B   C   E

00002471    Sd3a28f471  0   10.31   
00002471    Sd3a28f471  1   10.31
When the E column value of these two rows matches then I need to give 1 in F column for the record where C has 1, but not for the record where C has 0

Comment: Then why 3 rows: `00002471    Sd3a28e471  0   9.31    242.370000  1` have 1 since c = 0 and also this row: `00002471    Sd3a28e471  1   343.00  343.000000  0` has the min e if you group by a,b,c (it is the only one) and has c=1 why the result is 0?